# What is the Linux equivalent of Fiddler?

Tags: linux, software-rec, fiddler

On Windows I like using Fiddler to scan TCP streams and save them.

Is there a similar tool to do this under Linux?

Comment: Sorry, Janos, but we don't consider such questions on-topic anymore. There is no single answer to this question and it's polling for a list of software that fulfills a certain requirement.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - it runs on Linux as well.

> Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a
>   developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between
>   their machine and the Internet. This includes requests, responses and
>   the HTTP headers (which contain the cookies and caching information).

Comment: But compared to Fiddler it is very expensive - 50USD per license whereas Fiddler is free...

Answer (score 7):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is network protocol analyzer and is available for Linux, PC and Mac. Like fiddler it allows you to scan TCP streams and allows deep inspection of hundreds of protocols. Please take a look at features in the [about page.](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html)

Comment: That is only part of the features. I think a closer equivalent is Firebug at http://getfirebug.com

Between those two, almost all features should be covered.

Comment: @Jeff F. I am sorry to say that your answer is not corect, Firebug is just a browser traffic analyzer , if that is a application level.
Wireshark is a interface level(sniffer interface) and can capture all kind of traffic and protocols, including USB traffic. +1 Wireshark Long live!

Answer (score 0):

[OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) is a little different in theory but you can find the same functions and many more security-related ones.

Its main aim is to help you find vulnerabilites in web applications and information gathering are very similar to Fiddler or Charles (Proxying, analysing and geenrating POSTs, etc.)

It's also a free and open source tool (Apache License 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **Burp Suite** fits your needs? has a free version: http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html